# List all queues on a queue manager

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I am trying to list all the queue names on a queue manager using Java. I am not allowed to use PCF messages. I would like to know if there is another way to do this. Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 4):

The MQ API is focused on things a business application needs to do.  For security and other reasons, business apps are expected to know which queues they need so there's no "inquire queue names" function as part of the API.

Instrumentation and admin apps are expected to have the need to do things like query the configuration of the queue manager.  The PCF and command line messages are provided for this purpose.

If the application in question is a business application, it would break the expected security model to grant it both business privileges and admin/instrumentation privileges.  The MQ Admin would be correct to question why a business app needs to query the list of defined queue.

If the application in question is intended to perform instrumentation or admin tasks, then it *must* be granted appropriate privileges, including access to put messages onto the Command Queue.

If the app's ID is properly permissioned, access to the Command Queue can be granted without also giving away full MQ Admin access.  In fact, MQ Explorer has a set of roles that grant read-only access to Explorer users and those work great for instrumentation apps.